# How can I trim all forms of white space (tabs, new lines, …) from a string in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

How can I trim all forms of white space (tabs, new lines, …) from a string in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

`Trim()` only removes white spaces. For example, the following voice command will type `[tab]test`

```
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
Sub Main
    s = vbTab & "test"
    s = Trim(s)
    SendKeys s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the work I did here:

> CheckNewPara is here:
>   http://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=2739&discTab=true&messid=11427&parentid=11409&FTVAR_FORUMVIEWTMP=Single
>   Or search the forum for that term, and note, what it does is look back
>   to see what existing character(s) exist prior to where the cursor is
>   when you call the function to decide what to do next

One can adapt and create the following:

```
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13 Professional on Windows 8.1
Sub Main
    s = vbTab & " " & vbTab & "test"
    s = myTrim(s)
    MsgBox """" & s & """"
End Sub
Function myTrim ( s As String )
    While Left(s,1)=Chr(9) Or Left(s,1)=Chr(10) Or Left(s,1)=Chr(13) Or Left(s,1)=" "
        s=Mid(s,2)
    Wend
    While Right(s,1)=Chr(9) Or Right(s,1)=Chr(10) Or Right(s,1)=Chr(13) Or Right(s,1)=" "
        s=Mid(s,1,Len(s)-1)
    Wend
    myTrim = s
End Function
```

Naturally, you can reference your myTrim function in a common Uses comment file, so you only have to write it once.

Hth,

Comment: Thanks, your solution works great. Do you know if it is possible to use the `String.Trim` method? I read on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez(v=vs.90).aspx: "The LTrim, RTrim, and Trim functions remove spaces from the ends of strings. To remove other forms of white space, such as tab characters, use the `String.Trim` method.". But I cannot manage to get the `String.Trim` method works: when trying to say the voice command I get the usual "Please, correct syntax error(s) before saving a macro".

Comment: Dragon NaturallySpeaking Advanced Scripting is based on WinWrap Basic V6 -- which is old and out-of-date.  Check here for a chart showing many of the differences and similarities between WinWrap Basic V6 (WW), Microsoft VB Script 5 (VBS), and Microsoft VBA 6 (VBA):

http://www.pcspeak.com/scripting10/advanced_scripting_vs_vba.pdf

At any rate, WWB does not support treating strings as objects the way a modern language would -- so no, string.trim method won't work.

Comment: Thanks, good to know! it's annoying that Dragon NaturallySpeaking Advanced Scripting isn't based on some more modern language. By the way you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer in [Which programming languages can I use with Dragon Advanced Scripting?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41009401/395857)

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a Trim command that will remove the tab and other whitespaces automatically, but you can remove the whitespaces one by one by using the Replace command.

```
Sub Main
    s = vbTab & "test"
    s = Trim(s)
    s = Replace (s, Chr(9), "") ' Replaces the tab character written in ASCII code with nothing
    s = Replace (s, Chr(10), "") ' Replaces the LF written in ASCII code with nothing
    s = Replace (s, Chr(13), "") ' Replaces the CR written in ASCII code with nothing
    SendKeys s
End Sub
```

This is a partial solution: It will remove all those whitespaces, even within the string. If you'd like to keep those, you'll have to find a way to test if the first or last chars are whitespace and the replace them with nothing. I can't figure that one out quickly as I haven't done it before.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that you can use "Replace" in Dragon NaturallySpeaking Advanced Scripting. But you don't need it for the OP's request, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution, indeed a bit less subtle than the other one :-) as a side note, I am looking for hands-free stenomask for speech recognition, any pointer is very welcome:  [Device that allows the use a stenomask without having to hold it with one's hand](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6395/40)

Comment: Ha! Yes, indeed -- subtle.  Btw, you can easily adapt my solution to trim off the back end of a string, too.  Just change all the `Left`s to `Right`s and the processing as follows: `s=Mid(s,1,Len(s)-1)`.  Do you want me to edit my answer to include (I ask bc I'd like if you marked it as Answered but want to make sure it is)?  Enjoy!

Comment: @PGilm sounds good, thanks! Answer accepted (I cannot upvote as I have already done so yesterday).