# Which programming languages can I use with Dragon Advanced Scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I read on http://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/scriptref/Content/scrptref/scripting_language_quickref.htm :

> Dragon Advanced Scripting lets you use programming languages such as Microsoft® VBA to program commands that can perform virtually any function on the computer with voice commands.

Which programming languages can I use with Dragon Advanced Scripting on Microsoft Windows, besides Microsoft® VBA?

Comment: You can potentially add other languages through the references menu in Advanced Scripting if they go through COM. Read an example here: https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=12&threadid=18116. Then some people have used Python to interface with Dragon and create commands with it (DragonFly, Vocola). I'm not aware of any other programming language in Dragon.

Comment: @user99572isfine Thank you. Could you please convert your comment as an answer? (on Stack Exchange comments are deleted  from time to time,  and questions with no answer and no upvote may also be deleted, which is unfortunate)

Comment: I did not post that as an answer because I cannot definitely answer your question. Now I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the above reference to multiple languages that can be used with Dragon can be attributed to sloppy language use by a marketing guy or to the fact that you can reference other languages through COM.

I'm not aware of any other programming language in Dragon - FWIW, I have been hanging around on speech recognition forums since 2006 and I've never heard of anything besides Advanced Scripting being officially supported by Dragon.

You can potentially add other languages (such as Word VBA) through the References menu in Advanced Scripting Commands Editor if they go through COM. Read an example here: https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=12&threadid=18116.

Then some people have used Python to interface with Dragon and create commands for it (DragonFly, Vocola), which is more of a hack and not supported in any way by Nuance. Other programs can interface with Dragon as well (API, SDK) to create commands in languages other than Advanced Scripting (eg. KnowBrainer).

To sum up, there are ways to use other languages with Dragon, but it's not like it's right under your nose.

Comment: In addition, as you touched on, the SDK API can be used by any language that supports COM, and in fact, many (most) syntax examples are provided in Visual Basic and C++. E.g., I use AutoHotKey regularly to interact with Dragon. Check out here: http://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/scriptref/Content/scrptref/promptvalue_function.htm